# Setting Font of a Label on Codename One Not Working

Tags: java, intellij-idea, fonts, codenameone

I am trying to change the default font of the labels in my theme in CodenameOne. Going through theme.res, I have created a new font through bitmap. When I change the font of Labels within theme.res, the preview works perfectly and shows the font that I want. However, when I actually run my program, the font has changed from the default, but isn't the font I had made. There is a popup besides bitmap that says "deprecated!" but I'm not sure what that means and why my font only works in preview.
Thanks!

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: There is no code to show. I clicked "add Font", set it to italicized Times New Roman, and then within the Label selected the font for it to be the font I had created. I would add pictures, but stackoverflow doesn't really allow for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use bitmap fonts!!!

They are old and they look awful. Just place the TTF file you want in the src directory and select it. I would recommend using native fonts though. See the [fonts section in the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/theme-basics.html#_fonts).

Answer (score 1):

As per wikipedia; **Deprecation**: *In current technical usage, for one to state that a feature is deprecated is merely a recommendation against using it. It is still possible to produce a program or product without heeding the deprecation.*

It basically means that the library/class/method has been replaced by an improved version.
Such as, Date was deprecated by the release of Calendar.

As for your font issue, I think we need to see some code examples!